# Can you create a pop-up in Craft?

Tags: templating

Is there a way to create a pop-up for when someone visits the site on the backend of Craft?

Comment: To be clear, someone logs into the Craft control panel, and you want a pop-up/modal to display in the control panel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to build a custom module that's built for the admin panel. A starter on doing so can be found here:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/

I think what you'll want is to trigger some code on the LOGIN event, but only if that user is has access to the CP. A quick search in Craft's Events lookup (located here: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/events.html#event-code-generator) reveals this might be the event you want (feel free to dig / try others):

craft\elements\conditions\users\LastLoginDateConditionRule::EVENT_AFTER_VALIDATE

Events Guide:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/events.html

You would write this in modules/Module.php (a pre-setup file in Craft CMS where you can code this) or your own custom equivalent.

Comment: You may want to code your own popup and NOT use the flash messaging, as its a bit reserved for particular use cases in the CP. Per this conversation: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6218